# How to filter a ListView by the last pressed item on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app where I need to filter meals by category and day of week (it's a weekly menu). I created 3 classes, `Category`, `DayOfWeek` and `Meal`, respectively. The `Meal` class have two parameters call `Meals` page.

I want to show the items where the `idCategory` contains the parameter `id` from the `Category` class, and the `idDayofWeek` contains the parameter `id` from the `DayofWeek` class. When I filter only one of the parameter, it works just fine, but when I try to filter both, it doesn't work.

Codes below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  const Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.color = Colors.orange,
  });
}
```

```
class DayOfWeek {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;

  const DayOfWeek({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.color = Colors.black,
  });
}
```

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

import 'package:integra_foods/models/category.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:integra_foods/models/day_of_week.dart';

import '../models/meal.dart';

List<Category> DUMMY_CATEGORIES = const [
  Category(
    id: 'c1',
    title: 'Gastronomia',
    color: Color.fromRGBO(222, 1, 59, 1),
  ),
  Category(
    id: 'c2',
    title: 'Gourmet',
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 1, 255),
  ),
  Category(
    id: 'c3',
    title: 'Light',
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 148, 38),
  ),
];

List<DayOfWeek> DUMMY_DAY_OF_WEEK = const [
  DayOfWeek(
    id: 'd1',
    title: 'Segunda',
    color: Color.fromRGBO(222, 1, 59, 1),
  ),
  DayOfWeek(
    id: 'd2',
    title: 'Terça',
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 1, 255),
  ),
  DayOfWeek(
    id: 'd3',
    title: 'Quarta',
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 148, 38),
  ),
  DayOfWeek(
    id: 'd4',
    title: 'Quinta',
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 148, 38),
  ),
  DayOfWeek(
    id: 'd5',
    title: 'Sexta',
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 1, 148, 38),
  ),
];

List<Meal> DUMMY_MEALS = [
  Meal(
      id: 'm1',
      description: 'teste comida gourmet 2a feira',
      ingredients: [
        'ingredients',
        'ingredients',
        'ingredients',
      ],
      idCategory: 'c2',
      idDayOfWeek: 'd1',
      dtInclusion: DateTime.now(),
      dtAlteration: DateTime.now(),
      usAlteration: 'fulano',
      image: 'https://i.ibb.co/42MvRwm/Integra-Foods-1.png'),
  Meal(
      id: 'm2',
      description: 'teste comida gastronomia 3a feira',
      ingredients: [
        'ingredients',
        'ingredients',
        'ingredients',
      ],
      idCategory: 'c1',
      idDayOfWeek: 'd2',
      dtInclusion: DateTime.now(),
      dtAlteration: DateTime.now(),
      usAlteration: 'fulano',
      image: 'https://i.ibb.co/42MvRwm/Integra-Foods-1.png'),
  Meal(
      id: 'm1',
      description: 'teste comida light 4a feira',
      ingredients: [
        'ingredients',
        'ingredients',
        'ingredients',
      ],
      idCategory: 'c3',
      idDayOfWeek: 'd3',
      dtInclusion: DateTime.now(),
      dtAlteration: DateTime.now(),
      usAlteration: 'fulano',
      image: 'https://i.ibb.co/42MvRwm/Integra-Foods-1.png'),
];
```

```
class _DaysOfWeekMealsScreenState extends State<DaysOfWeekMealsPage> {
  var status = StatusReserva.n;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final dayOfWeek = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as DayOfWeek;
    final category = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Category;

    final DateTime date = DateTime.now();

    final dayOfWeekMeals = widget.meals.where((meal) {
      return meal.idDayOfWeek.contains(dayOfWeek.id) &&
          meal.idCategory.contains(category.id);
    }).toList();
```

it returns an error "type 'DayOfWeek' is not a subtype of type 'Category' in type cast See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the same argument as 2 different types

```dart
final dayOfWeek = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as DayOfWeek;
    final category = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Category;
```

The error says that the argument is of typedayOfWeek but you are trying to cast it as a Category

**EDIT**

You can pass the values as named arguments. Created a small demo for your reference

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: PageOne(),
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  PageOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Category categoryItem = const Category(
      id: 'c2',
      title: 'Gourmet',
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 1, 255),
    );
    DayOfWeek dayOfWeekItem = const DayOfWeek(
      id: 'd2',
      title: 'Terça',
      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 162, 1, 255),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: MaterialButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: const Text("Open day of week meal page"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => DayOfWeekMealsPage(
                          category: categoryItem,
                          dayOfWeek: dayOfWeekItem,
                        )));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DayOfWeekMealsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Category category;
  final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
  const DayOfWeekMealsPage(
      {Key? key, required this.category, required this.dayOfWeek})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DayOfWeekMealsPage> createState() => _DayOfWeekMealsPageState();
}

class _DayOfWeekMealsPageState extends State<DayOfWeekMealsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print((widget.category));
    print(widget.dayOfWeek);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  const Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.color = Colors.orange,
  });
}

class DayOfWeek {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;

  const DayOfWeek({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.color = Colors.black,
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i make it understand that i need to validade both classe's id's at the filter? because if i remove the second line it says that 'category' isn't initialyzed. Can you give me an example of how it would work right please?